# How to override the str method when rendering StackedInline field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a many to many relationship:

```
class GroupeCategoriesCategorie(models.Model):
    groupe_categories = models.ForeignKey(GroupeCategories,
                                          related_name='groupe',
                                          verbose_name=_(u'Groupe'))
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie,
                                  related_name='categorie',
                                  verbose_name=_(u'Catégorie'))

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'{} / {}').format(self.groupe_categories, self.categorie)
```

I always need a representation like the `__str__` method before **except** when rendering in the admin. Why? My `admin.py` looks like that:

```
class GroupeCategoriesCategoriesInline(CollapsedStackedInline):
    model = GroupeCategories.liens.through
    fk_name = 'groupe_categories'
    raw_id_fields = ('categorie',)
    extra = 0    

class GroupeCategoriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ('description', 'exemple',)
    inlines = (GroupeCategoriesCategoriesInline,)
```

And here's the result:

[image: django manytomany]

As you can see, when you edit a `GroupeCategories`, you see the `Description` field first, and this `description` is repeated for each manytomany row just after... this is ugly. I'd like to override the `__str__` method, but **only here**. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily override the template used by the inline:

```
class GroupeCategoriesCategoriesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    [...]
    template = 'yourapp/admin/stackedinline.html'
```

Get a copy of this template:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html