# Customizing Django's implicit ManyToManyField's "through" table?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have two models which are joined through a `ManyToManyField`. I did not specify a `through` table manually, so Django created one implicitly.

Can I now somehow customize that `through` table, specifically to alter its `___str___` function?

Basically, I'm trying to override the "row title" a `TabularInline` admin class uses, like in these questions:

- [Remove or edit object name in admin.TabularInline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377591/remove-or-edit-object-name-in-admin-tabularinline)
- [How to override the str method when rendering StackedInline field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583077/how-to-override-the-str-method-when-rendering-stackedinline-field)
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-users/d0QPIAklSug

But I'd like to avoid customizing the template or creating a "relationship table" explicitly, as right now it's managed by Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey-patch the `__str__`. If for example your model looks like:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela_set = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)
```

Then you can monkey patch with:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela_set = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)

def mystr(self):
    return 'str-of-through-model'

ModelB.modela_set.through.__str__ = mystr
```

But this is not very good practice. Ideally, you make a through-model, and add methods to that model.